# Does a DreamSpark account allow me to publish apps to the Windows 8 Store?

Tags: windows-8, dreamspark

I have a DreamSpark account. Does it allow me to publish my apps to the Windows 8 store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You will need a store token to create a free dev account at windows store. You can get the store token from your dreamspark account.

- Once you login into Dreamspark account, click app development tab.
- Under Windows 8 tile, click "Learn more"
- Scroll down to step 3, click on "Get your registration code"
- Use this code to create your account at dev.windows.com

Yes, you can publish paid apps too after completing your tax profile.

Comment: what are the requirements needed to complete tax profile successfully in india ? [is this enough ? or i should post a new question for the answer for this question]

Comment: No right here is fine I guess, I am new here too :D You need a credit card to create a dev account at store.Having a valid bank account associated to that card would suffice. Please vote up the answer if that answers your question.

Comment: Voting up requires minimum 15 reputations. i don't have that much sorry.